# ASP.NET Send big C# list<int> as blob or arraybuffer to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket, web-worker

I have a very big ( 4-5 mil ) list of integer in C# that i would like to send to a website so it may be processed via javascript

I am thinking about using arraybuffer that achieve that end, but i do not know how to send an array buffer ( from my backend ) to frontend ( to my javascript) so i may deserialize my c# list array into a typed javascript array.

I been investigating about using websockets, would that be faster than ajax?

I plan to do the deserialization of this array in a web worker and put in in indexeddb.

I also want to bring about 40 of such arrays to be put in indexeddb over a period of time ( couple of minutes ).

Comment: WebSockets are for continuous sending and receiving.  As this is a one time thing (right?), there is no need for such overhead.  I would stick with JSON.

Comment: yea but i plan to bring 40 such arrays in indexeddb over a period of time, wont be one time thing but 40 but you are right they are not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax for calling server after some period. WebSockets may fall because it is not made to transfer big amount of data.

You can use jsstore for doing indexeddb query (it executes query in web worker). If you are using plain indexeddb then it is also good. So if you are using jquery for ajax and jsstore for indexeddb. The code will be like this -

```
$.get(url, function(results){
   //considering results is array of integer
   var Connection = new JsStore.Instance('Db_name');
   Connection.insert(
   {
     Into:'Table_name',
     Values:results,
     OnSuccess: function(rowsAdded){
       alert(rowsAdded +' rows added');
     },
     OnError: function(error){
       console.log(error)
     }
   })
 })
```

You can use setInterval for calling the above code after some time period.